# Should one adjust p-values for multiple testing corrections in research?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, p-value, multiple-comparisons

I have seen some medical research papers which do various testings and none of them will adjust p-values accordingly. A lot of p-values are p-values of testing some simple hypothesis.

Why people do not report adjusted p-values for multiple comparisons in those research papers with tables after tables of p-values? I would assume that the any test done in paper is not equivalent to some other test done in the paper and they are not testing nested hypothesis.

Comment: Relevant (I disagree with Rothman, mostly because of the scalability and adaptability of false discovery rate methods of adjusting for multiple comparisons, but he puts forth a cogent critique): Rothman, K. J. (1990). [No adjustments are needed for multiple comparisons](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/20065622.pdf). *Epidemiology*, 1(1), 43–46.

Answer (score 4):

The researcher may only be interested in controlling each per-comparison error rate rather than a particular family-wise error rate.  If the researcher makes it clear that many hypotheses were investigated then the reader can interpret each p-value with a grain of salt or perform their own multiplicity adjustment.  Additionally, the p-value may be interpreted as the weight of the evidence for competing hypotheses rather than used in an accept/reject framework.  Even with strict control of a family-wise error rate, no hypothesis is proven false with a single small p-value nor is it proven true with a large one.

The challenge with multiplicity adjustments is defining the appropriate family of hypotheses.  Should the family be restricted to only the "primary" hypotheses in an experiment?  Should it include all of the hypotheses investigated in an experiment?  Why should the family be limited to only those hypotheses in a particular experiment?  Should the family include hypotheses from other experiments to be investigated (or previously investigated) by the experimenter?  Taken to an extreme, multiplicity adjustment will force the experimenter to retain nearly every null hypothesis.

In my opinion the only sensible approach is to interpret the p-value as the weight of the evidence.  Any decision or conclusion drawn from the results is tentative.  This may be the approach taken by some journals.

Comment: +1 Just a note: Although any specific application of FDR methods uses some set of comparisons, they do not assume this set constitutes a "family" (i.e. expected rejection probabilities do not change if you alter the set of comparisons, in sharp contrast to FWER methods).

Comment: My preference is to simply order the hypotheses by ascending p-value.  If there is interest in reproducing/replicating the results using limited resources then select the top hypotheses according to affordability.  I think it should be more a matter of time, money, and scientific interest than family-wise error rates or false discovery rates.

Comment: While the false discovery rate is presented as an objective measure it can also be viewed as a Bayesian posterior belief probability, though according to most developments the prior isn't clear or obvious.  FDR is the *expected* proportion of false discoveries.  Can anyone comment on what prior this expectation is with respect to?

Comment: +1 I agree with this answer, and I have written a more extended explanation of the issues in section 3.2 of this open-access chapter: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

Comment: @GeoffreyJohnson Accruing evidence that not all null hypotheses are true? In otherwords step-by-step evidence of a non-zero true discovery rate?